# Why does grep not show colors despite --color=always?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, colors

Works:

```
echo '\example' | grep --color=always -i '.example'
```

Works:

```
echo '\example' | grep --color=always -i '\\example'
```

Matches, but missing colors:

```
echo '\example' | grep --color=always -i '\example'
```

Comment: Since `\e` in certain circumstances is short for `<escape>`, I'm assuming that the `\e` at some point is interpreted as this and that it messes up the colouring (which uses escape-codes).  See also `echo 'e\example' | grep --color=always -i 'e\example'` (no match).  Note too that depending on your shell and the shell options set in that shell, `\e` will or will not be interpreted as `<escape>` by `echo`.

Comment: @Kusalananda No shell should be transforming `\e` inside single quotes, so both echo and grep will be seeing two characters. The output from the first line shows that echo is not doing the transformation of `\e` to escape, so we are left with grep. doing the backslash transformations. This is supported by the output from the second version and also your `e\example` not matching. So now we are left with bugs in grep. Removing the `-i` from the third line shows only `example` matching. So this looks like a bug in gnu grep (tested with version 3.3).

Comment: @icarus `echo 'hello\nworld'` outputs two lines in a default `zsh` shell (and `\e` eats the next character), but I only mentioned the potential issues with `echo` as a general precaution. Your comment seems reasonable.

Comment: Note: `-i` seems important, at least in my Debian.

Answer (score 2):

#### Finding the discrepancy

I spent some time poking through the source code for grep and narrowed down the problem a bit.

The main issue lies in the function `print_line_middle`. See this loop construct:

```
for (cur = beg;
     (cur < lim && ((match_offset = execute (compiled_pattern, beg, lim - beg,
                                             &match_size, cur)) != (size_t) -1));
     cur = b + match_size)
{
```

#### The discrepancy

The issue is that for example #3 above, the `match_offset = execute(...)` call **is** equal to -1. This result influences when the printing is done and thereby what colors are used.

#### Is this a bug?

I have no idea :) but feel free to send the devs an email. From the README:

> Send bug reports to bug-grep@gnu.org.